# Gas fireplace partially lighting

Tags: gas, fireplace

When I'm lighting my gas fireplace, there are two rows of flames that typically ignite... An upper and lower part. The upper always lights first followed by the bottom. Lately the lower part has not been completely lighting. This morning only a quarter of the bottom lit. Any ideas what the problem is? And do you think there's any safety issue with running it this way temporarily until it is resolved.... It is our only source of heat today until our new furnace is installed

Answer (score 1):

I find the burner needs maintenance when not burning with all ports, usually the holes are plugged with rust and a wire brush works great to clean, in some cases with heavy cast burners I have needed to poke a steel wire through the holes to clear the debris out. Is there a safety issue? Yes you are not getting proper combustion this can lead to excess gas build up and even higher CO levels, usually burners are easy to clean give it a try with a wire brush and see if that solves the problem, if not a wire or small drill bit can be used to clear the holes.